# svg animateMotion cann't add this dom,this dom just have one circle!the circle has no child

Tags: javascript, svg

it doesn't work!who can tell me why? the circle has no children animateMotion!

```
 var circle=document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","circle");
                circle.setAttributeNS(null,"cx",0);
                circle.setAttributeNS(null,"cy",0);
                circle.setAttributeNS(null,"r",7);
                circle.setAttributeNS(null,"fill",'red');
            var animateMotion=document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","animateMotion");
                animateMotion.setAttributeNS(null,"dur",'6s');
                animateMotion.setAttributeNS(null,"repeatCount",'indefinite');
                animateMotion.setAttributeNS(null,'path',path);
                circle.appendChild(animateMotion);
                dom.appendChild(circle);
                console.log(circle.appendChild,dom)
```

Comment: What is `path` in your code? Please provide an [MCVE]

Comment: if i do write 'dom.appendChild(circle)',this console's circle has the children animateMotion! but if i add,the circle has no children;

Comment: Using your exact code, I get a circle with an animateMotion child. Whether the animation should work visually is not something we can guess from your code, but are you sure the element isn't there at all? are you using IE?

Comment: ok,does this grammar using the svg has something wrong?if it hasn't,i must check my code more cautious！

Answer (score 1):

Pressumably, you're trying to re-create the animation shown at the following url: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateMotion

The first thing that stands out is the way you're trying to append the path. This doesn't correspond to the SVG shown at the above link. In fact, the *animateMotion* element doesn't have a *path* attribute. What it **does** have however, is a child element of type *mpath*.

If I adjust the generating code such that all of the elements necessary for the animation - i.e the circle, the path the enimateMotion and the mpath element, then I generate seemingly okay markup, albeit with some(all) of the self-closing tags mis-represented as a normal tag, albeit with no content, merely attributes.

However, this somewhat broken SVG  still doesn't work! If I then clean-up and change 'normal' tags to self-closing ones, it works fine.. Clearly, I'm also doing something wrong.

Firstly, the modified javascript/html

```
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
    var dom = byId('svg');

    var path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","path");
    path.setAttributeNS(null,"d","M10,110 A120,120 -45 0,1 110 10 A120,120 -45 0,1 10,110");
    path.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke","lightgrey");
    path.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke-width","2");
    path.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","none");
    path.setAttributeNS(null,"id","theMotionPath");
    dom.appendChild(path);


//    <path d="M10,110 A120,120 -45 0,1 110 10 A120,120 -45 0,1 10,110"
//      stroke="lightgrey" stroke-width="2" 
//      fill="none" id="theMotionPath"/>

    var circle=document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","circle");
        circle.setAttributeNS(null,"cx",0);
        circle.setAttributeNS(null,"cy",0);
        circle.setAttributeNS(null,"r",5);
        circle.setAttributeNS(null,"fill",'red');
    var animateMotion=document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","animateMotion");
        animateMotion.setAttributeNS(null,"dur",'6s');
        animateMotion.setAttributeNS(null,"repeatCount",'indefinite');
    //  animateMotion.setAttributeNS(null,'path',path);
        circle.appendChild(animateMotion);


    var mPathObj = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","mpath");
        mPathObj.setAttribute("xlink:href",'#theMotionPath');
        animateMotion.appendChild(mPathObj);

//      <mpath xlink:href="#theMotionPath"/>    

        dom.appendChild(circle);
        console.log(circle.appendChild,dom);
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <svg id='svg' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    </svg>
</body>
```

Now, for the generated (broken) SVG

```
<svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <path d="M10,110 A120,120 -45 0,1 110 10 A120,120 -45 0,1 10,110" stroke="lightgrey" stroke-width="2" fill="none" id="theMotionPath"></path><circle cx="0" cy="0" r="5" fill="red"><animateMotion dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite"><mpath xlink:href="#theMotionPath"></mpath></animateMotion></circle></svg>
```

Finally, the working one:

```html
<svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <path d="M10,110 A120,120 -45 0,1 110 10 A120,120 -45 0,1 10,110" stroke="lightgrey" stroke-width="2" fill="none" id="theMotionPath"/>
 <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="5" fill="red">
  <animateMotion dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite">
   <mpath xlink:href="#theMotionPath"/>
  </animateMotion>
 </circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I find the wrong in my codes!By the way,setAttribute is Same as setAttributeNS or not!

Comment: @RobertLongson - thank you very much! I'd certainly not expected to see _you_ around here.